# Python Error : ImportError: No module named 'xml.etree'

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I am simply trying to parse an XML file:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

but this gives me:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
ImportError: No module named 'xml.etree'
```

I am using Python 3.5. I have tried to same code with Python 2.7 and 3.4 but I always get this error. I thought that the XML libraries come as standard. Also, I can see that in my Lib folder:

[image]

So why can't it pick up the module? I am really confused. Do I have to make some change in an environment variable somewhere?

Please help.

Comment: never mind, false alarm. my dev package was named xml. i changed the name and now it works

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Remove the file `xml.py` or a directory `xml` with a file `__init__.py` in it from your current directory and try again. Python will search the current directory first when importing modules. A file named `xml.py` or a package named `xml` in the current directory shadows the standard library package with the same name.

As pointed out in a comment by KeshV, you also need to remove the file `xml.pyc`, if it exists. In Python 2 it will be in the same directory as `xml.py`. In Python 3 it will be in the sub directory `__pycache__`. In General, as long as the `*.py` file is around, you can savely delete the corresponding `*.pyc` file because Python will re-create it upon import of the `*.py` file.

Comment: i dont have a file of that name

Comment: my file is called parse.py

Comment: Do you have a  sub-directory `xml` in there?

Comment: yes, my package was named xml. now i changed the name and it works :) thanks

Comment: also remove xml.pyc , just removing xml.py is not enough

Comment: @KeshV Thanks for the comment. Added a section to my answer mentioning this.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand a little more about how python works.

Comment: is there an alternative, if i want to keep my name?

Answer (score 15):

Your script name is: `xml.py`?

Change it and it should work.

Answer (score 5):

A local `.py` file overwrites the pre-defined module. Remove all the files that named xml in the current folder.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers that already point to local Python modules: In case you have added other directories to your path, also make sure to check those for modules called `xml.py` or packages called `xml`.

For me that was the issue when calling Sphinx with a `conf.py` file that added several directories to the path.