# pycopy-xml.etree.ElementTree not installing

Tags: python-3.x, package

I am trying to install the package xml.etree.ElementTree using the command (both from within PyCharm as well as from command line)

```
pip install pycopy-xml.etree.ElementTree
```

The process fails with the following output

```
Collecting pycopy-xml.etree.ElementTree
  Using cached pycopy-xml.etree.ElementTree-0.1.3.tar.gz (1.9 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\xxxxxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-npssdelu\\pycopy-xml-etree-elementtree\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\xxxxxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-npssdelu\\pycopy-xml-etree-elementtree\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-eh_gxd2r'
         cwd: C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-npssdelu\pycopy-xml-etree-elementtree\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tokenize.py", line 392, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\xxxxxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-npssdelu\\pycopy-xml-etree-elementtree\\setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------
```

Help to sort this out appreciated.

Comment: I downloaded the dependent package **pycopy-xmltok2** and tried to install it within PyCharm but that failed as well.  How can I reset the environment please?

Comment: I tried to uninstall and reinstall PyCharm but the the package would not install

Comment: In the new installation I tried installing **openpyxl** and it worked. So the issue seems to be with xml.etree.ElementTree. Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: Link to Answer: [Python Error : ImportError: No module named 'xml.etree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633954/python-error-importerror-no-module-named-xml-etree)