# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xml'

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, python-3.8

When  I was trying to install python package via pip with command "pip install pandas", I got this error

```
  File "c:\users\user1\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\plistlib.py", line 65, in <module>
    from xml.parsers.expat import ParserCreate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xml'
```

Comment: something went wrong.... try it again

Comment: [Does this answer your question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33634074/8237838)

Comment: @May.D It doesn't. `xml.py` or `xml/__init__.py` can be imported as in `import xml`, only submodules/subpackages cannot. But the OP has problem with the top-level `import xml`.

Comment: Armen, please check — do you have a directory `c:\users\user1\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\xml/` with `__init__.py` and all subpackages?

Comment: Thanks for comment. No, I don't have

Comment: @ArmenMelkonyan You have a broken standard library. You need to reinstall Python with stdlib.